# How to find the word after a given pattern using cut?

Tags: text-processing, cut

I have a file that looks like this:

```
-config1
-config2 param2
-config3 param3a param3b
-config4 param4
```

and I can use the following to extract `param2`:

```
echo $(<file) | cut -d' ' -f3
```

However I would like to fix it such that I always get the word after
`-config2`, such that if these get re-arranged or something is
inserted, my command will still work. What should I be looking at?

Clarification: there may be more than one params on any given line (or none at all), however there will always be at most one `-config` option per line.

Comment: The answers posted so far make different assumptions about what can vary in the layout of your input file. Can you clarify? Do we know that `-config2` is followed by a single word on its line? Can there be multiple `-configX` options on the same line?

Comment: @dhag right now they are only -config param or simple -config (which toggles a flag), but I suppose there could be -config1 param1a param2b at some point in the future - I was using echo to convert the lines into a single one with spaces, but that's more of a work-around than a feature.  There shouldn't be more than 1 '-' on any line however.

Comment: Oh, OK. Then I misunderstood what you meant when I edited your post. I'll revert that bit. Shouldn't it be `cut -f4`, to select `param2`, in that case? I will also update my answer to correspond to this new piece of information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use awk for this

```
awk '/^-config2/ {print $2}' file
```

It print the second argument of lines starting with `-config2`. The `^` means the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
perl -ne 'if (/-config2\s*(.*)/) { print "$1\n"; }'
```

This looks for lines matching `-config2`, and then prints the rest of
the line (`\s*` matches an arbitrary amount of white space, `(.*)`
matches anything and binds it to `$1`).

My previous answer, which assumed that `-config2` was followed by a
single word:

```
perl -ne 'if (/-config2\s*(\S+)/) { print "$1\n"; }'
```

This looks for lines matching `-config2`, and then prints the first
token after it (`\s*` matches an arbitrary amount of white space, `(\S+)` matches a non-empty sequence of non-whitespace characters and binds it to `$1`).

Answer (score 1):

A variation with sed:

```
sed -n 's/^-config2 //p' file
```

`-n` suppress automatic printing

`s/^-config2 //` substitute `-config2` and trailing space on line start with nothing in pattern space

`p` print pattern space